# Speed up the linq group by statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table like this

```
UserID   Year   EffectiveDate   Type    SpecialExpiryDate
     1   2015   7/1/2014        A   
     1   2016   7/1/2015        B       10/1/2015
```

there is no `ExpriyDate` in the table because it is only valid for one year, so the expiry date can be calculated from the effective date by adding a year.

The result I want to get is like this (the current year's effective date and the next year's expiry date)

```
UserID   EffectiveDate   ExpiryDate
     1    7/1/2014        7/1/2016
```

And If the user's type is B, then there will be a special expiry date, so for this person, the result will be

```
UserID   EffectiveDate   ExpiryDate
     1    7/1/2014        10/1/2015
```

Here is the code I wrote

```
var result = db.Table1
            .Where(x => x.Year>= 2015 && (x.Type == "A" || x.Type == "B"))
            .GroupBy(y => y.UserID)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.FirstOrDefault().Year)
            .Select(t => new
                         {
                             ID = t.Key,
                             Type = t.FirstOrDefault().Type,
                             EffectiveDate = t.FirstOrDefault().EffectiveDate,
                             ExpiryDate = t.FirstOrDefault().SpecialExpiryDate != null ? t.FirstOrDefault().SpecialExpiryDate : (t.Count() >= 2 ? NextExpiryDate : CurrentExpiryDate)
                          }
                    );
```

The code can get the result I need, but the problem is that in the result set there are about 10000 records which took about 5 to 6 seconds. The project is for a web search API, so I want to speed it up, is there a better way to do the query?

**Edit**

Sorry I made a mistake, in the select clause it should be

`EffectiveDate =  t.LastOrDefault().EffectiveDate`

but in the Linq of C#, it didn't support this LastOrDefault function transfered to sql, and it cause the new problem, what is the easiest way to get the second item of the group?

Comment: Are you going to show/return 10K results ? You should looking for paging.

Comment: @Habib, it is an API, so I have to return all the data at once I think

Comment: How much logic can you push to your database?  LINQ isn't as good as most servers/mainframes when it comes to processing large amounts of data.

Comment: @pita I'm not familiar with any APIs that actively promote returning 10k simultaneous records over paging.  In addition, there is certainly an expectation that can be set if you are going to return 10k rows of data.

Comment: Those `FirstOrDefault`'s have my highly suspicious that this query actually does what you want it to do in the first place.

Comment: @DavidL I am working with the company who is creating the new website for us, the decision of paging is a little bit out of my control I guess.

Comment: Instead of calling `x.FirstOrDefault().` repeatedly you can do it like `.GroupBy(y => y.UserID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Year)`

Comment: @EZI, then how to get the count of each group ?

Comment: Then return an anonymous object in *Select* like `new{Item=x.FirstOrDefault(), Count=x.Count() }`

Comment: Add .AsNoTracking() to then end of your query.  This could speed it up some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate the calculated data on the fly, using a `View` in your database.

Something like this (pseudocode):

```
Create View vwUsers AS 
    Select 
        UserID, 
        Year, 
        EffectiveDate, 
        EffectiveData + 1 as ExpiryDate,   // <-- 
        Type, 
        SpecialExpiryDate
    From 
        tblUsers
```

And just connect your `LINQ` query to that.

Comment: Thanks, actually I created a stored procedure in the sql database, code is like select ..... from Users join (select MIN(EffectiveDate), MAX(some calculation to get ExpiryDate))

Comment: @pita - Then just do an `OrderByDescending` before you group. Then the `.Take(1)` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var result =
    db
        .Table1
        .Where(x => x.Year>= 2015 && (x.Type == "A" || x.Type == "B"))
        .GroupBy(y => y.UserID)
        .SelectMany(y => y.Take(1), (y, z) => new
        {
            ID = y.Key,
            z.Type,
            z.EffectiveDate,
            ExpiryDate = z.SpecialExpiryDate != null
                ? z.SpecialExpiryDate 
                : (t.Count() >= 2 ? NextExpiryDate : CurrentExpiryDate),
            z.Year,
        })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Year);
```

The `.SelectMany(y => y.Take(1)` effectively does the `.FirstOrDefault()` part of your code. By doing this once rather than for many properties you may improve the speed immensely.

In a test I performed using a similarly structured query I got these sub-queries being run when using your approach:

```
SELECT t0.increment_id
FROM sales_flat_order AS t0
GROUP BY t0.increment_id

SELECT t0.hidden_tax_amount
FROM sales_flat_order AS t0
WHERE ((t0.increment_id IS NULL AND @n0 IS NULL) OR (t0.increment_id = @n0))
LIMIT 0, 1
-- n0 = [100000001]

SELECT t0.customer_email
FROM sales_flat_order AS t0
WHERE ((t0.increment_id IS NULL AND @n0 IS NULL) OR (t0.increment_id = @n0))
LIMIT 0, 1
-- n0 = [100000001]

SELECT t0.hidden_tax_amount
FROM sales_flat_order AS t0
WHERE ((t0.increment_id IS NULL AND @n0 IS NULL) OR (t0.increment_id = @n0))
LIMIT 0, 1
-- n0 = [100000002]

SELECT t0.customer_email
FROM sales_flat_order AS t0
WHERE ((t0.increment_id IS NULL AND @n0 IS NULL) OR (t0.increment_id = @n0))
LIMIT 0, 1
-- n0 = [100000002]
```

(This continued on for two sub-queries per record number.)

If I ran my approach I got this single query:

```
SELECT t0.increment_id, t1.hidden_tax_amount, t1.customer_email
FROM (
  SELECT t2.increment_id
  FROM sales_flat_order AS t2
  GROUP BY t2.increment_id
  ) AS t0
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT t3.customer_email, t3.hidden_tax_amount
  FROM sales_flat_order AS t3
  WHERE ((t3.increment_id IS NULL AND t0.increment_id IS NULL) OR (t3.increment_id = t0.increment_id))
  LIMIT 0, 1
  ) AS t1
```

My approach should be much faster.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I just found my mistake that I need to get the effective date from the LastOrDefault item, so I can't just use take(1) to only get the first item of each group